# Consigo fazer em Python um código melhor que este? Sou iniciante na linguagem e gostaria de saber se estou no caminho certo

Tags: python, revisão-de-código

Objetivo desse programa é receber o raio do usuário e calcular a área do circulo.

Sou iniciante em Pyhton, então gostaria de saber se esse é o código mais eficiente que poderia fazer para resolver o problema, ou se há outra maneira mais simples (desde que não seja uma função pronta do Python para calcular a area do circulo rs). Faço essa pergunta, pois saberia se estou no caminho certo ou se posso melhorá-lo, torná-lo mais simples.

```
from math import pi


def area_circulo(raio):
     return pi * float(raio) ** 2


def nao_numerico(raio):
    print('Digite apenas números!')


def maior_que_zero():
    print('Raio precisa ser maior que 0!')


def se_numero(n):
    try:
        float(n)
    except ValueError:
        return False
return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    raio = input('Informe o raio: ')

if se_numero(raio):
    if float(raio) < 1:
        maior_que_zero()
    else:
        area = area_circulo(raio)
        print('Area do circulo =', area)
else:
    nao_numerico(raio)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, dá pra ser mais simples.

Por exemplo, você converte o `raio` para `float` várias vezes: primeiro para ver se é número mesmo, depois para ver se é menor que 1, e depois para calcular a área. Em vez disso, por que não converter apenas uma vez?

```
from math import pi

try:
    # lê e já tenta converter para número
    raio = float(input('Informe o raio: '))

    # se chegou aqui, é porque a conversão deu certo
    if raio < 1:
        print('Raio precisa ser maior que 0!') # veja no final considerações sobre esta mensagem
    else:
        print(f'Área do círculo = {pi * raio ** 2}')
except ValueError: # se não digitou número, cai aqui no except
    print('Digite apenas números!')
```

Ou seja, ao ler o número, já tente converter para `float`. Se der certo, você continua. Se der errado, ele cai no `except` e você imprime a mensagem de erro.

Também não coloquei a área em uma variável, pois se você só quer imprimir o valor e não vai fazer mais nada com ele, nem precisa de uma variável (basta imprimir o resultado da conta diretamente).

Em um código simples como esse, criar esse monte de funções só está complicando à toa. Mas claro, se quiser muito usar funções para tudo, basta chamá-las nos respectivos lugares. Eu só tiraria a função que verifica se é número, pois me parece desnecessário (a própria tentativa de conversão já indicará se deu certo ou não):

```
from math import pi

def area_circulo(raio):
     return pi * raio ** 2

def nao_numerico(): # se o raio não é usado, não passe ele como parâmetro
    print('Digite apenas números!')

def maior_que_zero():
    print('Raio precisa ser maior que 0!')

try:
    raio = float(input('Informe o raio: '))
    if raio < 1:
        maior_que_zero()
    else:
        print(f'Área do círculo = {area_circulo(raio)}')
except ValueError:
    nao_numerico()
```

Veja que a função `nao_numerico` não está usando o raio para nada, então não tem motivo para passá-lo como parâmetro.

E tem outra coisa estranha: você diz que o raio deve ser maior que zero, mas testa se o valor é menor que 1. Não deveria ser `if raio <= 0`?

Comment: Esta análise que precisava, obrigado amigo.